# Loading different FXML files from a controller

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, fxml

I apologize as I understand that the question is a bit broad in nature. What I want to achieve is having the ability to load different FXML files (located in different packages) when specific conditions are met, for example when a button is pressed or when a certain condition is satisfied. So far I've managed to load a file when a button is pressed.

```
@FXML
private AnchorPane rootPane;

@FXML
private Button btn;


@FXML
private void loadLoginWindow(javafx.event.ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

    AnchorPane pane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("login/MainWindow.fxml"));

    rootPane.getChildren().setAll(pane);
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // TODO
}
```

And it works fine but for one button and one handler only, as soon as another is added it stops working, it seems that only one can work at the time. So clearly I'm missing a bunch of important info but every tutorial I've had a look at doesn't address this point because they don't even get there (They all revolve around a single file, or they rely on hiding and showing panes from the same file)

Does anyone have any good tutorial or comprehensive guide to do this kind of things?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of showing the working one, it's better to show us the non-working one.

Comment: As I said, the non working one looks exactly like the working one, except that it's called loginwindow 1 and pane1 and so on.

Comment: How is the other one not working? Is there an exception? Does it simply not work? Are there different unexpected results? Currently this question is unanswerable since the description of the error is insufficient...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What can happen is the link to the controller within the FXML file can be incorrect. Even though the file location may not exist, the application will still build.

`<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" fx:controller="main.MainController">`

The pathway in the fx:controller need to be correct.

Cheers!